# Examples of references for mathematical approaches in bioinformatics that are applicable to linguistics?

Tags: bioinformatics, mathematical-models, theoretical-biology, literature

Do you have any classic references for mathematical approaches in bioinformatics that are applicable to linguistics (or vice versa)?

**EDIT**
 
I am mainly interested in approaches to reconstruct the history of languages, the rate of language mutation, phylogenies of languages, etc.

Comment: An approach to do what exactly? The question is too vague to answer.

Comment: @fileunderwater,approaches to construct history of language,the rate of language mutation,the phylegen,etc.

Comment: I'm interested in whether you've crossposted this question on Linguistics SE. I wonder if you'd get different or similar answers.

Comment: @Oreotrephes,sorry,I have not crossposted this question on Linguistics SE.I think I will get no answer,since my other question and answers on the Linguistics usually get downvoted,very interesting.Of course,there are some persons standing up for my answer.

Comment: Strange – I hope these answers help you at least get started!

Comment: @Oreotrephes,thank you,and I have browsed the articles every one recommended,to tell you the truth,some results are too interesting to be true.Is this interesting? I think some researchers are eager to find something interesting

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of more recent papers dealing with phylogenetic methods in reconstructing language history as well, including work by Colin Renfrew and Quentin Atkinson.

Here are two recent high-profile papers. Unfortunately, both are still behind paywalls, but even reading the list of papers they cite / that cite them would be a great way to answer your question.

- [**Bouchard-Côté A, Hall D, Griffiths TL, Klein D**. 2013. Automated reconstruction of ancient languages using probabilistic models of sound change. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 110: 4224–4229.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1204678110)
- [**Gray RD, Drummond AJ, Greenhill SJ**. 2009. Language phylogenies reveal expansion pulses and pauses in Pacific settlement. Science 323: 479–483.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1166858)

Maybe not quite as high-profile, but available online, one of my classmates did his (superb) undergraduate thesis as a Biology/Linguistics double major in exactly this topic. I think it could be a very useful place to start, although there have certainly been developments in the field in the last six years:

- [**Saunders, A.** 2006. Linguistic Phylogenetics of the Austronesian Family: a performance review of methods adapted from biology.](http://www.swarthmore.edu/SocSci/Linguistics/Papers/2006/saunders_arpy.pdf)

See also the wikipedia page [Quantitative Comparative Linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_comparative_linguistics), this Stanford [how-to](http://www.stanford.edu/~tylers/notes/qp/Linguistic_phylogenetics_4-23-09.pdf), and this interesting article [Linguistic Phylogenies Are Not the Same as Biological Phylogenies](http://geocurrents.info/cultural-geography/linguistic-geography/linguistic-phylogenies-are-not-the-same-as-biological-phylogenies#ixzz2dPRUbM6y).

Answer (score 2):

[Branching processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process) (from probability theory) were originally developed to study the extinction of family names ([Galton-Watson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process)), but are also used to study biological extinction and general evolutionary processes. One example that applies ideas from branching processes and phylogenetic methods to reconstruct ancient languanges can be found in [Forster & Toth (2003)](http://www.pnas.org/content/100/15/9079.long). The basic concepts of branching processes can be found in most textbooks on probability theory, but a classic reference is [Harris 1963](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486495086) ([pdf](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2009/R381.pdf)).

This is maybe not exactly what you are after but should be related to your question.